# Python application launch position (location) on monitors

Tags: python

I have been given a project in python and I'm not too familiar with it but I understand the basics due other coding work I've done.
The task is to basically make the application launch in last location it was closed.
There is no save button and no config (xml / ini etc.) currently used so I would assume it would need to create one of these, if not existing, or update an existing one upon closure of the window.

Everyone has different size monitors / monitor layouts and resolutions so is there a module that can assess this and save the X,Y co-ords per user configuration?
Or is there a better way to do this using the modules listed below? Or do I need to import an additional module?

These are the current modules imported:
import os
import sys
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Forgot to post an update:
I managed to get this working perfectly into the existing app using J Arun Mani method.
I used os module to define the local directory where the file should be written to / read from and boom it works flawless. Thanks again

Comment: Um, just simply save the coordinates and size of the window in some configuration file on the user's machine in a format of your choosing, and upon opening the app/window, read that back in and reposition the window if required?

Comment: The users would arrange things as they wish on their particular setups, and that gets saved on their local workstations. Your app doesn't need to know the physical layout of the screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the methods, `Gtk.Window.get_position` and `Gtk.Window.move` to get and set coordinates of window. ([Link to doc](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Window))

But be aware that the placement of windows is users' preference and is taken care by window manager. So normally, you should not mess with it.

A simple example to demonstrate what you wanted:

```py
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk


def window_start(win):
    try:
        fp = open("win_coords")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("No file !")
        return
    coords = fp.read()
    x, y = eval(coords) # Don't use eval if you can't trust the file
    print("Moving to ", coords)
    win.move(x, y)
    fp.close()


def window_close(win, event):
    fp = open("win_coords", "w")
    coords = tuple(win.get_position())
    print("Writing coordinates ", coords)
    fp.write(str(coords))
    fp.close()
    win.destroy()
    Gtk.main_quit()


label = Gtk.Label(label="Hello world")
win = Gtk.Window()
win.add(label)

win.connect("delete-event", window_close) # Connect to get the coordinates
win.show_all()
window_start(win)

Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Oh. Then use the methods I described above.

Comment: So upon closing the application Gtk.Window.get_position writes to a file in their profile and upon launching Gtk.Window.move will move it to those saved co-ords?

Comment: @SimonT I updated my answer to include a demo snippet that does what you asked. You would have got (0, 0) possibly because you tried to get position of the window after it is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try giving this a go.

Comment: With Python 2.7, I can't say anything except moving to Python 3 as soon as possible :)